# не могу построить многоугольник по заданным рандомом точкам С# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, polygon

Я хочу построить многоугольник по заданным точкам. Для этого я выполняю 1 и 2 пункт Алгоритма Грэхема. Далее я планирую выполнить 3 пункт, чтобы посмотреть отличается ли массив точек после выполнения пункта 3, ибо если да, то я могу сказать, что изначально многоугольник не был выпуклым. То есть мне нужно построить многоугольник из рандомного количества вершин, которые располагаются по рандомным координатам, а потом сказать является выпуклым построенный многоугольник или нет. Я вдохновился этой статьей: https://habr.com/ru/articles/144921/, однако многоугольник не строится (к пункту 3 соответственно я еще не приступал).

Я пробовал разные способы, но остановился на алгоритме Грэхема. Судя по всему сортировка вставками в нем работает некорректно, так как случаются пересечения сторон многоугольника.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TrueLab4_habrEdition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Graphics g;
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = CreateGraphics();
            Random random = new Random();
            int z = random.Next(6, 8);
            Point[] points = new Point[z];
            int[,] pointsS = new int[z, 2];
            Point[] newPoints = new Point[z];
            int[] P = new int[z];

            // генерация точек
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                int x = random.Next(50, 100);
                int y = random.Next(70, 170);
                points[i] = new Point(x, y);
            }

            // заполнение массива индексов точек
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                P[i] = i;
            }

            // копирование массива points в pointsS
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                pointsS[i, 0] = points[i].X;
                pointsS[i, 1] = points[i].Y;
            }

            grahamscan(pointsS, P);

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < P.Length; i++)
            { 
                int x = pointsS[P[i], 0];
                int y = pointsS[P[i], 1];
                newPoints[j++] = new Point(x, y);
                Console.WriteLine(P[i]);
            }
            show2d(pointsS);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
            g.DrawPolygon(pen, newPoints);
        }
        void grahamscan(int[,] pointsS, int[]P)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < pointsS.GetLength(0); i++) 
            {
                if (pointsS[P[i], 0] < pointsS[0, 0])
                {
                    (P[i], P[0]) = (P[0], P[i]);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < pointsS.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                int[] a = { pointsS[P[0], 0], pointsS[P[0], 1] };
                int[] b = { pointsS[P[j-1], 0], pointsS[P[j-1], 1] };
                int[] c = { pointsS[P[j], 0], pointsS[P[j], 1] };
                while (j > 1 && rotate(a, b, c) < 0)
                {
                    (P[j], P[j-1]) = (P[j-1], P[j]);
                    j -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
        double rotate(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C)
        {
            return (B[0] - A[0]) * (C[1] - B[1]) - (B[1] - A[1]) * (C[0] - B[0]);
        }

        void show2d(int[,] p)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < p.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(p[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR5Av.png)

Comment: Однако выпуклая оболочка случайного набора точек обычно включает в себя не все точки. Какова точная формулировка задачи?

Comment: 1. Обход Грэхема можно запускать только на предварительно отсортированном наборе точек.
2. Чтобы превратить набор точек в многоугольник, не нужно строить выпуклую оболочку.

Comment: @MBo в описании я указал: _"Далее я планирую выполнить 3 пункт, чтобы посмотреть отличается ли массив точек после выполнения пункта 3, ибо если да, то я могу сказать, что изначально многоугольник не был выпуклым."_. Если не все точки, то многоугольник был невыпуклым)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для правильной работы обхода Грэхема точки должны быть отсортированы. Иначе обход имеет право рисовать самопересекающиеся ломанные, что вы и видите.

Чтобы превратить набор точек в многоугольник, не нужно строить выпуклую оболочку:

1. Сортируем точки лексикографически.
2. Между крайними точками проводим воображаемый отрезок и делим все точки на те что ниже и те что выше этого отрезка.
3. У тех что выше меняем порядок на обратный и соединяем с теми что ниже. Многоугольник готов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RandomPolyForm : Form
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new RandomPolyForm());
    }
 
    public RandomPolyForm()
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Click Me!";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        Controls.Add(b);
    }
 
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        int n = random.Next(3, 40);
        Point[] points = new Point[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            points[i] = new Point(
                random.Next(50, ClientRectangle.Width - 50),
                random.Next(50, ClientRectangle.Height - 50)
            );
        }

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
        g.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
        pen.Dispose();

        Array.Sort(points, new PointComparer());

        Point[] upper = points.Where(p => ccw(points[0], points.Last(), p)).ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(upper);
        Point[] lower = points.Where(p => !ccw(points[0], points.Last(), p)).ToArray();
        lower.CopyTo(points, 0);
        upper.CopyTo(points, lower.Length);

        pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        g.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
        pen.Dispose();

    }

    private class PointComparer : IComparer
    {
        int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
        {
            Point p1 = (Point) x;
            Point p2 = (Point) y;
            if (p1.X < p2.X) { return -1; }
            if (p1.X > p2.X) { return 1; }
            if (p1.Y < p2.Y) { return -1; }
            if (p1.Y > p2.Y) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private bool ccw(Point p0, Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return (p2.Y - p0.Y) * (p1.X - p0.X) - (p1.Y - p0.Y) * (p2.X - p0.X) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я думал, что 2 пункт алгоритма Грэхема, это и есть сортировка точек относительно опорной точки. У меня была надежда на то, что если я выполню первые 2 пункта алгоритма, то построю произвольный многоугольник, а выполнив 3 пункт, построю правильный многоугольник, а потом посмотрю отличается ли многоугольник после 3 пункта от того, что построен после 1-2 пунктов. Если отличается, то многоугольник невыпуклый, а если нет, то выпуклый. Но почему моя гипотеза неверна? Точки то я сортирую.

Comment: Вообще до того, как я узнал о алгоритме Г. Я также выполнял 1 пункт вашего алгоритма, затем проводил прямую между крайними точками, и если были пересечения, то перегенерировал последнюю точку. Стэк конечно переполнялся. Но тогда мне никто не рассказывал про 3 пункт вашего алгоритма)))) Как это понять с мат точки зрения? Почему мы инверсим массив верхних точек?

Comment: И массив "нижних" точек и массив "верхних" точек упорядочены слева-направо. Чтобы описать многоугольник нам нужен цикл. Перевернув "верхний" массив и склеив его с нижним, получаем цикл.

Comment: Выглядит как 3Д с вайрфреймами :)